# Sentry how to specify the name of the operation via the Go package OpenTelemetry?

Tags: go, sentry, open-telemetry

How do I specify the name of the span operation in the OpenTelemetry package of the Go language? Span names from the documentation list: https://develop.sentry.dev/sdk/performance/span-operations/
I tried to specify through an attribute, but it just creates another attribute with the same name:

```
ctx, span := trace.Tracer.Start(ctx, "name", trace.WithAttributes(attribute.String("Operation", "http.server")))
defer span.End()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ctx, span := trace.Tracer.Start(ctx, "name", trace.WithAttributes(attribute.String("faas.trigger", "http.server")))
defer span.End()
```

OR

```
import semconv "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/semconv/v1.4.0"

ctx, span := trace.Tracer.Start(ctx, "name", trace.WithAttributes(semconv.FaaSTriggerKey.String("http.server")))
defer span.End()
```